# bas64 decode to csv file, sed script

Tags: sed, base64, decode

I have the following script to extract text inside "reportBody" text, but I need also to decode this text from a new file to base64. How can I do this?
Here's a script:

```
cat $1 | tr "\n" "|" | grep -o '<reportBody>.*</reportBody>' | sed 's/\(<reportBody>\|<\/reportBody>\)//g' | sed 's/|/\n/g' | sed '/^\s*$/d' > $2
```

tried :

```
cat $1 | tr "\n" "|" | grep -o '<reportBody>.*</reportBody>' | sed 's/\(<reportBody>\|<\/reportBody>\)//g' | sed 's/|/\n/g' | sed '/^\s*$/d' | base64 -d $2 > $2
```

but it doesn't decode it,

Can I overwrite the same file or at least save decoded text in a new one? without calling addition modules from python etc.

Note: File contains 20k+ symbols to decode.

Comment: Your `... | base64 -d $2 > $2` is wrong on at least one item. Try `...|base64 $2 > $2.fixed`. But I'm also wondering how `base64` is supposed to read from the stdin provided the pipeline before it, AND from a opening a file? Does that really work? (and there are other issues, but if your pipleline is mostly working (except for base64), then I won't try to fix it).  Good luck.

Comment: Yep, I'm confused too that this hmmm *badword* code works in someway, don't wanna try to fix something xD thanks! 

but I'm curious how can I improve this code?

Comment: I would boil this down to a basic test first, i.e. `echo "stuff That should translate" | base64 -d` . If that's not working then update your Q to show simple input, current output, expected output, and your current code. Once you're getting the output you need for simple test case, then it will be easier to debug all of those steps. Good luck.